# Does hibernate search indexing annotation supports 'copy_to' attribute of Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm curious to know, if we can merge two or more than two fields into one and persist that to the Elastic Sever while creating the indexes through hibernate search. Currently we use the @Index annotation on an individual fields to index that field to the Elastic Database.

But is there a possibility to use the "copy_to" option of the elastic search on the annotations side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `copy_to` option of Elasticsearch is not currently available in Hibernate Search. There are currently no plans to add it.

As a workaround, you can simply target multiple fields from the same query.

Comment: Thanks @yrodiere for the quick response. But I am trying to do that and not getting proper results. I'v put up the question under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545925/select-query-by-concatenating-3-fields-with-multiple-or-conditions-on-the-same

Would appreciate, if you can provide your views on that.