# @Transient with @Field annotated field not showing in index on elastic server

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search, nhibernate-search

Using Hibernate Search 5.9 and elastic server 5.6.10.

I'm trying to persist data from 3 fields into a single field with @Transient annotation. But though the fields shows up in the index structure, the same does not show up when I query the index with curl/chrome. Its not present on the index and the data is lost this way.

Code:

```
@Transient
                @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
                private String fullAgentNumber = "";

                public String getFullAgentNumber() {
                                return this.fillr1 +""+ this.rpt0agt0nr +""+ this.fillr2;
                }
```

Result on Index:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "master_policy_index",
        "_type" : "com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Basclt1400TO",
        "_id" : "00,0004087,WCV,05,00",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "00,0004087,WCV,05,00",
          "location" : "00",
         "symbol" : "WCV",
          "module" : "00",
          "policy0num" : "0004087",
          "master0co" : "05",
          "cltseqnum" : 277,
          "addrseqnum" : "1",
          "policies" : [
            {
              "location" : "00",
              "symbol" : "WCV",
              "module" : "00",
              "policy0num" : "0004087",
              "master0co" : "05",
              "trans0stat" : "P",
              "id02" : "02",
              "eff0yr" : "118",
              "eff0mo" : "03",
              "eff0da" : "15",
              "exp0yr" : "119",
              "exp0mo" : "03",
              "exp0da" : "15",
              "fillr1" : "000",
              "rpt0agt0nr" : "0",
              "fillr2" : "358",
              "tot0ag0prm" : "0.00",
              "line0bus" : "WCV",
              "issue0code" : "N",
              "type0act" : "NB"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expect the transient field to contain the data am trying to persist while creating the index.
Also I believe once the field has the data, it will too update if the fields its referencing is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the `@Field` annotation on an object field which is, apparently, always empty. Hibernate Search will thus always index an empty string.

You don't need an object field for transient methods. Try this:

```
@Transient
                @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
                public String getFullAgentNumber() {
                                return this.fillr1 +""+ this.rpt0agt0nr +""+ this.fillr2;
                }
```

Comment: Though got it working the same way, Thanks @yrodiere for your response and sharing the logic behind it, which is more important to understand :) .